# Ошибка в конструкторе CustomView

Tags: java, android

У меня есть CustomView который рисует текст по ширине. На андроиде 7.0 все хорошо работает, но на андроиде 4.1 выдаёт ошибку конструктора на CustomView. А именно на эти строки:

```
public JustifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);

}

public JustifiedTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}

public JustifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
```

Не понимаю что не так. Код CustomView:

```
public class JustifiedTextView extends View {
Paint  mTextPaint;
String  mText;
ArrayList<TextBlockDrawable> mTextBlocksDrawable;
int mTextSize;
ColorStateList  mTextColor;
int mCurTextColor;
int  w, h;
float[] widths;
float   minSymWidth;
int     font_descent;
int     font_interline;
int     font_line_height;
int     mLinesCount;
LineBreaker mLineBreaker;

public JustifiedTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}   

public JustifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public JustifiedTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}

public JustifiedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    ColorStateList textColor = null;

    mTextPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    final Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    String text = "";
    int textSize = 57;

    TypedArray a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.JustifiedTextView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    int n = a.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);

        switch (attr) {
            case R.styleable.JustifiedTextView_text:
                text = a.getString(attr);
                break;
            case R.styleable.JustifiedTextView_textColor:
                textColor = a.getColorStateList(attr);
                break;
            case R.styleable.JustifiedTextView_textSize:
                textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, textSize);
                break;
        }
    }
    a.recycle();

    setTextColor(textColor != null ? textColor : ColorStateList.valueOf(0xFF000000));
    setRawTextSize(textSize);
    setText(text);

    mLineBreaker = new LineBreaker();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (TextBlockDrawable textBlockDrawable : mTextBlocksDrawable) {
        canvas.drawText(mText, textBlockDrawable.start, textBlockDrawable.end, textBlockDrawable.x, textBlockDrawable.y, mTextPaint);
    }  }

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (w != widthSize) {
        w = widthSize;
        mLineBreaker.buildTextBlocks();
    }

    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        h = heightSize;
    }else{
        h = mLinesCount * font_interline +  font_descent;
    }

    //MUST CALL THIS
    setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}

class LineBreaker {
    int x, y;
    int                          posLenStart;
    int                          spacesLen;
    int                          posEOL;
    int                          len;
    ArrayList<TextBlockDrawable> words;
    TextBlockDrawable            word;
    TextBlockDrawable            textBlockDrawable;

    private void buildTextBlocks() {
        init();
        if (len == 0) return;

        initNewLine(0, 0);
        for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
            if (mText.charAt(pos) == ' ') {
                spacesLen += minSymWidth;
                finishLine(pos);
                words.add(textBlockDrawable);
                while (mText.charAt(++pos) == ' ') {
                    spacesLen += minSymWidth;
                }
                initNewLine(0, pos);
            }

            if (x + widths[pos] + spacesLen > w) {
                //scan back for first space
                posEOL = pos;
                do {
                    if (mText.charAt(pos) == ' ') {
                        pos++;
                        break;
                    }
                } while (--pos > posLenStart);

                //single word does not fit in single line
                if (pos == posLenStart) {
                    pos = posEOL;

                    newLineResetValues();
                    finishLine(pos);
                    initNewLine(0, pos);

                    posLenStart = pos;

                    x += widths[pos];
                    continue;
                } else if (pos < 0) {
                    //cant fit even 1 char
                    return;
                }

                redistributeSpaces();
                newLineResetValues();

                textBlockDrawable.x = x;
                textBlockDrawable.y = y + font_line_height;
                posLenStart = pos;
            }
            x += widths[pos];
        }
        textBlockDrawable.end = len;
        mTextBlocksDrawable.add(textBlockDrawable);
        mLinesCount++;
    }

    private void init() {
        y = 0;
        x = 0;
        posLenStart = 0;
        spacesLen = 0;
        mLinesCount = 0;
        words = new ArrayList<>();
        len = mText.length();
        mTextBlocksDrawable.clear();
    }

    private void initNewLine(int yOffset, int pos) {
        textBlockDrawable = new TextBlockDrawable(x, y + font_line_height + yOffset, pos);
    }

    private void finishLine(int pos) {
        textBlockDrawable.end = pos;
        mTextBlocksDrawable.add(textBlockDrawable);
    }

    private void newLineResetValues() {
        spacesLen = 0;
        x = 0;
        y += font_interline;
        mLinesCount++;
    }

    private void redistributeSpaces() {
        int widthTotal = w;

        if (words.size() <= 1) {
            words.clear();
            return;  }

        for (TextBlockDrawable wrd : words) {
            for (int i = wrd.start; i < wrd.end; i++) {
                widthTotal -= widths[i];}  } 

        int wordsCount = words.size() - 1;
        int spaceLen = widthTotal / wordsCount;
        int spacesMod = widthTotal % wordsCount;
        int spacesShift = 0;
        for (TextBlockDrawable word : words) {
            word.x += spacesShift;
            spacesShift += spaceLen;

            if (spacesMod-- > 0) {
                spacesShift++;
            }
        }

        words.clear();
    }
}

public void setTextColor(ColorStateList colors) {
    mTextColor = colors;

    int color = mTextColor.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0);
    if (color != mCurTextColor) {
        mCurTextColor = color;
        // установка цвета
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#4a148c"));
    }
}

private void setRawTextSize(int size) {
    if (size != mTextPaint.getTextSize()) {
        mTextSize = size;
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(size);

        FontMetricsInt fm = mTextPaint.getFontMetricsInt();
        font_descent = fm.descent;
        font_interline = fm.descent - fm.ascent;
        font_line_height = fm.descent - fm.ascent;

        float[] widths = new float[1];
        mTextPaint.getTextWidths(" ", widths);
        minSymWidth = widths[0];
    }
}

public void setText(String text) {
    mText = text;
    mTextBlocksDrawable = new ArrayList<>();

    widths = new float[mText.length()];
    mTextPaint.getTextWidths(mText, widths);
   if (w == 0) return;

    mLineBreaker.buildTextBlocks();

    invalidate();
}

static class TextBlockDrawable {
    int x;
    int y;
    int start;
    int end;

    TextBlockDrawable(int x, int y, int start) {
        this.start = start;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
} }
```

Comment: А ошибка то какая?

Comment: Полный лог: https://gist.github.com/AidosZhakupov/976e225f92e54e6e8db9e4006de9c18f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android в runtime не может найти некоторые конструкторы, у вас в большинстве из ник вызывается другой вместо super  для ранних api его нет, поэтому и падает, можно вынести общую логику в метод init(), вот примерно такая же проблема [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644234/android-inflate-exception-on-custom-view)